# Exercise 2.10 (ii) in Schaum, General Topology

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am working with problem 10 part (ii), chapter 2 in Schaum's *General Topology*. The problem is as follows:

> Let $A_n = \{ x \mid x \text{ multiple of } n \}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Find $\cup \{ A_i \mid i \in \mathbb{P} \}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers.

The answer key simply confirmed my intuition: "Every positive integer except $1$ is a multiple of at least one prime number." I know the answer and understand why it is so, but I wonder if I might ask you to look at my solution and perhaps suggest any improvements?

---

**My attempt**

My strategy revolves around the following theorem from the book:

> Theorem 2.4 Let $A$ be any set and, for each $p \in A$, let $G_p$ be a subset of $A$ s.t. $p \in G_p \subset A$. Then $\cup \{ G_p \mid p \in A \} = A$.

I guess that in plain English, this tells us that if we have a subset that contains $p \in A$ that is contained entirely in $A$, the union of all such subsets not only covers $A$, but is equal to $A$ (which sounds fair enough to me).

Since $1$ is not a prime, let us define $\mathcal{A} := \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$. I now claim that the set union we are seeking in this problem is equal to $\mathcal{A}$.

Let $a$ arbitrary number in $\mathcal{A}$. We have two cases:

1. If $a$ is a prime number, then clearly $a \in A_a$.
2. Assume $a$ is not a prime. Then there exists primes, $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ s.t. $a = \prod_{j=1}^n p_j$. In particular, $p_1$ is a prime, and $\prod_{j=2}^n p_j \in \mathbb{N}$, so $a$ is a multiple of $p_1$. This implies that $a \in A_{p_1}$.

Hence, for any $a \in \mathcal{A}$, we can find a subset s.t. $a \in A_p \subset \mathcal{A}$ where $p$ is a prime number. Thus from the theorem above, it follows that $\cup_{i \in \mathbb{P}} A_i = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$, which is also the answer given in the book.

---

Does this look okay? Again, I know and (think I) understand the answer, but since I am studying on my own for the time being, I don't have a teacher who can comment on my arguments. I would be grateful if I could ask you for comments or suggestions for improvement.

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: Well, actually your argument is the exact same as the one given ! You are just saying that every interger $\geq 2$ is a multiple of a prime number, therefore has to belong to one of the $A_{p_i}$. Be careful on one thing : you are not using the term "neighbourhood" correctly. "Neighbourhood" is a topological notion, here we are not talking about topology : you just consider a point belonging to a subset of a certain set.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you for the comment! Aha, I see what you mean that the argument is the exact same. It feels reassuring in a sense, to hear that that is the case, but now I also feel I have done something very redundant ... :/

Comment: I was indeed using the term "neighborhood" simply in the sense of "a set that contains ..." - I'll be more careful with the term from now on! What term might I use instead of "neighborhood" in this case?

Comment: Well, "a subset that contains..." is good !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Somehow I expected you to say that xD I found out that I had been using the term "neighborhood" sloppily, so I'm glad I posted here. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome :)